# Select not in Date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following table:

```
sDateTime                sItem        sValue
-------------------------------------------
2018-01-01 00:00:00      A            10
2018-01-01 00:00:01      A            15
2018-01-01 00:00:02      A            8
ff.
```

The data is on `second` base. What I want to know is, How can I know if there's a 'missed' second on my table?

Please advice.
Thank you.

Comment: Check on LAG function

Comment: What is meant by `MISSED SECOND`?

Comment: You can do 2 things to check this: either generate a table with all the values you should have (with a recursive CTE) and compare both, or use the `LAG` window function with `DATEDIFF` to compare if the difference is more than 1 second.

Comment: @DineshDB, I don't know if there's a lost second on my table. How can I check that?

Comment: @EzLo, Can you help me to put it on answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LAG` function you can compare each date with previous one and see if difference is more than 1 second.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Dates

CREATE TABLE #Dates (
    sDateTime DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #Dates (
    sDateTime)
VALUES
    ('1908-01-01 00:00:09'),
    ('2018-01-01 00:00:00'),
    ('2018-01-01 00:00:01'),
    ('2018-01-01 00:00:04'),
    ('2018-01-01 00:00:05')

;WITH Lag AS
(
    SELECT
        sDateTime = D.sDateTime,
        PreviousAvailableDateTime = LAG(D.sDateTime, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY D.sDateTime ASC)
    FROM
        #Dates AS D
)
SELECT
    L.sDateTime,
    L.PreviousAvailableDateTime,
    IsThereAGap = CASE WHEN DATEADD(SECOND, 1, L.PreviousAvailableDateTime) <> L.sDateTime THEN 'Yes' END
FROM
    Lag AS L
```

Results:

```
sDateTime               PreviousAvailableDateTime IsThereAGap
----------------------- ------------------------- -----------
1908-01-01 00:00:09.000 NULL                      NULL
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 1908-01-01 00:00:09.000   Yes
2018-01-01 00:00:01.000 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000   NULL
2018-01-01 00:00:04.000 2018-01-01 00:00:01.000   Yes
2018-01-01 00:00:05.000 2018-01-01 00:00:04.000   NULL
```

Comment: I have the following error `Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.`

Comment: At least one of your gaps is more than 70 years in difference (and the datediff explodes). I edited the solution to avoid using datediff.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know if there's a 'missed' second on my table?

As there shall be one record per second, subtract the last second from the first one and see if you have as many records as seconds.

```
select case when datediff(second, min(sdatetime), max(sdatetime)) = count(*) - 1
            then 'okay' else 'gaps exist' end as status
from mytable;
```

Comment: It doesn't show me on what date and on what second is missed. Is it possible to view the 'missed' record?

Comment: Ah, so you asked the wrong question. You don't want to know whether there exist missing seconds, but you want to know *which* seconds are missing. I've posted another answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all missing seconds, create them from min to max in a recursive query and remove from this set the ones you have in your table.

```
with seconds(second, last) as
(
  select min(sdatetime), max(sdatetime) from mytable
  union all
  select dateadd(second, 1, second), last from seconds where second < last
)
select second from seconds
except
select sdatetime from mytable
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CEL20691

Comment: @OP This is your only option if you want to see a record for each missing second. Beware that might take a while if your min date and max date are very far away.

Comment: I got this error `Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I always forget about this strange restriction in SQL Server. You'll have to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ISNULL(LAG(sDateTime) OVER (ORDER BY sDateTime),sDateTime) as PrevTime,sDateTime,sItem,sValue FROM [yourTable])t
 WHERE DATEDIFF(s,PrevTime,sDateTime)>1
```

This will give you the time of the record before the second was missed as well as the details of the record after the missed second.

Comment: I don't understand this either. The query looks fine to me.

Comment: Indeed, I think this is the simplest query you can come up with for the intended purpose